# Java answer to Top Coder program fails for test case and I cant figure out why

Tags: java

Im trying to solve a topcoder problem and my solution works for all example inputs excepts the one Im trying to run right now, in main. **It outputs 48 when it should output 92**. I know it has something to do with `if (minDefeatable >= bestCase) { return bestCase;}` in `minimalFatigue` function. I know this because if I remove that, it gives the correct answer for this particular test case but subsequently stops working on the others. Pulling hair trying to figure this out, any help much appreciated.

**Problem Statement**

Magical Girls are girls who have magical powers. They fight against evil to protect the Earth. Cosmic enemies have just attacked the Earth, and the Magical Girls are going to fight them. 
You are given a magicalGirlStrength that describes the Magical Girls: for each i, magicalGirlStrength[i] is the strength of one of the girls. You are also given a enemyStrength and a enemyCount that describe their enemies: for each i, there are enemyCount[i] enemies that each have strength enemyStrength[i]. 
Each Magical Girl will always fight one enemy at a time. A Magical Girl will defeat her enemy if her strength is greater than or equal to the strength of that enemy.

At the beginning of the fight the fatigue of each Magical Girl is 0. Each time a Magical Girl defeats an enemy, her fatigue increases by 1. 
The Magical Girls want to defeat all the enemies. That is, each of the enemies must be defeated by one of the Magical Girls. Additionally, the Magical Girls want to minimize the maximum fatigue among them. 
If it is impossible to defeat all of the enemies, return -1. Otherwise, return the smallest F with the following property: the Magical Girls can defeat all enemies in such a way that at the end the fatigue of each girl is at most F.

**Attempted Solution (w/ test case that fails in main)**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SpaceWarDiv2 {
    public static int minimalFatigue(int[] girlStrength, int[] enemyStrength, int[] enemyCount) {
        Arrays.sort(girlStrength);
        int girlsLeft = girlStrength.length;
        int enemiesLeft = sumInts(enemyCount);
        int[] canDefeat = new int[girlsLeft];
        calcDefeatable(girlStrength, enemyStrength, enemyCount, canDefeat);

        if (canDefeat[canDefeat.length-1] < enemiesLeft) return -1;
        int minDefeatable = canDefeat[0];

        int bestCase;
        while (girlsLeft > 1) {
            bestCase = (int) Math.ceil((double)enemiesLeft/(double)girlsLeft);
            if (minDefeatable >= bestCase) {
                return bestCase;
            } else {
                canDefeat = Arrays.copyOfRange(canDefeat, 1, canDefeat.length - 1);
                girlsLeft--;
                enemiesLeft -= minDefeatable;
                subtractFromInts(canDefeat, minDefeatable);
                minDefeatable = canDefeat[0];
            }
        }

        return canDefeat[0];

    }

    // Puts the max number of enemies a girl can defeat into an array, canDefeat, returns the index of
    // girl with the lowest defeatable count
    public static void calcDefeatable(int[] girlStrength, int[] enemyStrength, int[] enemyCount, int[] canDefeat) {
        int numGirls = girlStrength.length;
        int enemyGroups = enemyStrength.length;

        int defeatable = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numGirls; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemyGroups; j++) {
                if(girlStrength[i] >= enemyStrength[j]) {
                    defeatable += enemyCount[j];
                }
            }
            canDefeat[i] = defeatable;
            defeatable=0;
        }       
    }

    public static int sumInts(int[] ints) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            sum += ints[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void subtractFromInts(int[] ints, int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            ints[i] -= value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] girlStrength1 = {2, 3, 5};
        int[] enemyStrength1 = {1, 3, 4};
        int[] enemyCount1 = {2, 9, 4};

        int[] girlStrength2 = {14, 6, 22};
        int[] enemyStrength2 = {8, 33};
        int[] enemyCount2 = {9, 1};

        int[] girlStrength3 = {17, 10, 29, 48, 92, 60, 80, 100, 15, 69, 36, 43, 70, 14, 88, 12, 14, 29, 9, 40};
        int[] enemyStrength3 = {93, 59, 27, 68, 48, 82, 15, 95, 61, 49, 68, 15, 16, 26, 64, 82, 7, 8, 92, 15};
        int[] enemyCount3 = {56, 26, 12, 52, 5, 19, 93, 36, 69, 61, 68, 66, 55, 28, 49, 55, 63, 57, 33, 45};

        System.out.println(SpaceWarDiv2.minimalFatigue(girlStrength3, enemyStrength3, enemyCount3));
    }
}
```

**Example Input/Output**
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the first test should be 7 and the second test should be -1?

Comment: thats right. I updated the question with example input/output

Comment: I am not sure what that min defeatable means. But you are ignoring the cases where you have very few allies left and need to defeat a large number of enemies.  It exits on the very first loop and clearly the best case cannot be better than 56 as only one girl can defeat enemies greater than 80. Don't try and short circuit your loop, premature optimisation is the mother of all evil.